# Capture and modify http requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, httpclient

I have an Asp.net MVC application, which is connected to many Asp.net Web Api services.

It consumes the services using `HttpClient` requests. These methods exists in SDK libraries.

Is it possible to inspect (sniff) the REST requests, and before being sent, to add additional information in the Headers?

All the Asp.Net Web APIs are on the same local network as the Asp.net MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why do you call the REST api from the ASP.NET MVC controllers, you can call it directly from the Views using jQuery Ajax.

As for the inspection, you can do it using Fiddler, but you will have to update `web.config` for your ASP.NET MVC application by changing the default proxy like below:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy
          enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
        <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" 
               proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Make sure the proxy port for Fiddler is not changed from the default one 8888